# How to flip enemy patrolling side to side with Mathf.PingPong?

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a 2D platformer in Unity and I programmed one of the enemies to move back and forth with the ping pong function.

I would like to change the local scale depending on which direction the character is moving.

I have tried using two if statements where if the x value of the transform is below or above a certain number it will change the local scale accordingly, but that did not work.

Here is the code for the enemy:

```
public class Bunny: MonoBehaviour  {

    float min;
    float max;
    [SerializeField] float movmentSpeed = 0.5f;
    float movementDistance;
    public bool isHit = false;
      
    void Start() {
        min = transform.position.x;
        max = transform.position.x + 3;
        movementDistance = max - min;
    }
    
    void Update()  {
        if(isHit == false) {             
            transform.position = new Vector3(
                Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * movmentSpeed, movementDistance) + min, 
                transform.position.y, 
                transform.position.z
            );
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered getting the distance between `max` and `transform.position` and then dividing it by `movementDistance` and use this value for x factor of local scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without an extra member variable, and without overshooting past min/max. "Moving left" just means your new x is less than your old x. So, compare to see which one is bigger.

```
float newX = Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * movmentSpeed, movementDistance) + min;

transform.localScale = new Vector3(
    newX < transform.position.x ? -1 : 1,
    1,
    1
);

transform.position = new Vector3(
    newX,
    transform.position.y, 
    transform.position.z
);
```

Comment: This is going to sound pretty bad but i don't understand this part of ur code `transform.localScale = new Vector3(
    newX < transform.position.x ? -1 : 1,
    1,
    1
);`    Is this a shorthand for something I am unaware of? Unity is the only time I have done anything with c#

Comment: That's called the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C#). It chooses one of two values based on a condition: `booleanTest ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse`. When you're wondering about core programming syntax, [be sure to search StackOverflow first](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+question+mark+colon&searchOn=3) - it's probably already answered there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `Mathf.PingPong` function is that it doesn't tell you if the returned value is from the "Ping" or the "Pong" phase. When you need that information, for example because you need it to decide in which direction the sprite is supposed to face, then it is not going to be of much use. So we are going to need to use a different solution here.

One simple solution is to have a variable which states if the bunny is currently moving left or right. I would prefer to use an `enum` for that purpose, but when you don't know how to use enumerations yet, then you can just use a flag `bool isMovingLeft`.

Then you implement the Update function to behave differently depending on the state of that variable:

```
if (isMovingLeft) {
    transform.Translate(-movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
} else {
    transform.Translate(movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Then you need to detect if an event occurred which would cause the bunny to turn around, and then do everything that entails. In that case this event would be to exceed the "max" or "min" value:

```
if (transform.position.x > max) {
    isMovingLeft = true; // move left from now on       
    transform.scale.x = -1f;  // flip the sprite to mirrored
}
if (transform.position.x < min) {
    isMovingLeft = false; // move right again from now on
    transform.scale.x = 1f; // flip the sprite back to normal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, simple and easy way to flip in a specific range.
It worked for me.

```
if (transform.position.x > max)
            transform.Rotate(0f, 180f, 0f);
else if (transform.position.x < min)
            transform.Rotate(0f, -180f, 0f);
```

Comment: With the method they used in this question, the position will never be larger than `max` or smaller than `min`.